# Making 3D associative array with PHP

Tags: php, arrays

What I want to do is make a multidimensional associative array based on an column (event_id) from a MYSQL table.

An example of what i want is this array and the php code is what what I have so far

```
[
'event_id #1' : [{id=24, name: "Joe", code: "dsf34fsf"},{id=25,name: "Bob", code: "nlwr32"],
'event_id #2' : [{id=54, name: "Kevin", code: "sdfs"},{id=57,name: "Dan"}, code: "i5er343"]
]

    //Get tickets for the event if the user bought them
$query = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT id, name, event_id, code FROM tickets WHERE user_id='$user_id' ORDER BY event_id DESC");    

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $ticket_id = $row["id"];
    $code = $row["code"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $event_id =  $row["event_id"];                        
    $tickets[] = array($event_id => array('id' => $ticket_id, 'n' => $name, 'c' => $code));
}
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Without knowing what you have, showing us what you want is a little ambitious

Comment: I edited the question. The array is what I want and the PHP code is how far I've got in achieving that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change:

```
$tickets[] = array($event_id => array('id' => $ticket_id, 'n' => $name, 'c' => $code));
```

to:

```
$tickets[$event_id][] = array('id' => $ticket_id, 'n' => $name, 'c' => $code);
```

For your sample data, that will give a result like:

```
Array
(
    [event_id #1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 24
                    [n] => Joe
                    [c] => dsf34fsf
                )    
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 25
                    [n] => Bob
                    [c] => nlwr32
                )    
        )    
    [event_id #2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 54
                    [n] => Kevin
                    [c] => sdfs
                )    
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 57
                    [n] => Dan
                    [c] => i5er343
                )    
        )    
)
```